# How to use multiple navigation in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, page-layout, navigation, metadata-navigation

[image]

I need to achieve above navigation system in SharePoint 2013, so I choose structural navigation, So I copied and pasted the code snippet in the master page, I achieved the first navigation successfully, I am not sure how to achieve the second navigation because it comes under page layouts. whether I need to hard code the values or any other way to achieve it by using SharePoint default navigation (Structured or managed navigation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use table of contents web part in page to achieve the secondary navigation.Try these steps.

1) Go to site settings page of the site for which the navigation is required.

2) Click navigation and use managed metadata navigation for the current navigation.

3) Choose the term set(navigation items want to show)

4) Click Ok and go to the page where the secondary navigation is needed.

5) Edit page and add Table of contents out of the box web part in the page.

6) The navigation items will be displayed in the page and it is possible to align vertically and horizontally by editing in web part properties.